# SWIFTUI Present API

Tags: api, swiftui, alamofire

I would like to present in my users view the API with alamofire and I receive these errors.
Making optional not solving the problem.
Maybe I have done mistake in keypath but I don't understand the exact problem. [image]

This is the UsersView

```
    var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(.white)
        // Present the API Here ---
        List(self.viewModel.presenter.usersdata, id \.id) {
            Text($0.name)
            }
}
```

}

The presenter code

```
struct PostPresenter: Identifiable {

let id = UUID()
var data: [Datum]?
var usersdata: UserData?

init(with response: Response<[Datum]>) {
    self.data = response.data

}

init() {
    data = []
}
```

}

This is usersdata file from API.

```
struct UserData: Decodable {
let id: Int
let name, email: String
let gender: Gender
let status: UserData.Status

    
}

    enum Gender: String, Decodable {
        case female = "female"
        case male = "male"
    }
    
    extension UserData {
        enum Status: String, Decodable {
            case active = "active"
            case inactive = "inactive"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Much more than UIKit SwiftUI relies on non-optional values. In a declarative design a reasonable way is a `state` enum with associated values for example for *loading*, *loaded* with the data, *no data* and *error*. Depending on the state you can show different views. And `usersdata` is a single object which makes no sense in a List (designed for an array).

Comment: Do you think its better to present the data without List or initialiaze usersdara as an Array?